# Dense Rank in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

How can I get an equivalent of dense rank from SQL in Excel?

I have unsorted data (number of data varies from week to week) and the duplicates should have the same rank, i.e.

```
number    rank
6          1
12         2
23         3
6          1
6          1
```

I have found this solution

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (FREQUENCY($A$1:$A$10, $A$1:$A$10) > 0) * (A1 >= $A$1:$A$11) )

Note the extra row required in the second expression.
```

but I cannot use it as I do not know how many entries I will have and this one assumes I know the data set a priori.

Comment: ranking always require to know the whole dataset in advance. To ease the entering of your formula, you may use [dynamic ranges](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/830287/how-to-create-a-dynamic-defined-range-in-an-excel-worksheet).

Comment: You can use Indirect($G$1) and in G1 write $A$1:$A$10 and change G1 content each time the range changes, do the same for the second range with another cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))
```

To set the upper bounds of the range.  This will find the last cell that has a number and set that as the last cell in the range.  If the column has text instead then use `"ZZZ"` in place of the `1E+99`.

For the add one we just add one to the MATCH:

```
INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1))
```

So the whole formula will be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (FREQUENCY($A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)), $A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A))) > 0) * (A1 >= $A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,A:A)+1)) )
```

This is now dynamic, as values are added or removed from column A the reference will change accordingly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((FREQUENCY(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))),INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))))>0)*(A1>=INDIRECT("$A$1:$A"&(MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))+1))))
```

`Array Formula`  press `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` at the same time
  `MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A))`
Calculate the last cell in column A (gives the last non empty row in A)
Indirect will give the array reference (A1:A10) corresponding to last non empty row given by max
`MAX((A:A<>"")*(ROW(A:A)))+1`
For the array A1:A11

I prefer you name the range A1:A10 define name `Number` for example
A1:A11 `Numberplus`

`=SUMPRODUCT( (FREQUENCY(Number, Number) > 0) * (A1 >= Numberplus) )`

In that case you change the range only in Name Manager for both names only, your formula will remain the same